# Site not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

Can somebody explain me why my site is not displaying correctly in internet explorer:

http://shortener3.info/web/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of Doctype (Transitional with no URL) triggers [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), which causes browsers to emulate bugs that appeared in earlier browsers in order to cope with legacy code.

IE emulates a lot of features of IE 5.5, which was very very broken.

Use a Doctype that triggers [Standards (AKA Strict) mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

That might not solve all the problems, but it should be the first step in trying to resolve them.

Comment: I copied: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> and it worked! Thanks

Comment: @user Why not just `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: DTD validators are more mature than HTML 5 validators. No need to move on to a draft spec if you aren't going to benefit from it.